# Ошибка записи в память?

Tags: c++, файлы

https://pastebin.com/Cz7Dti3N Полный рабочий кусок

```
void Admin::read_admins()
{
    FILE* f;
    f = fopen("admins", "rb");
    fread(&Admin::admins_size, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fread(admins, sizeof(Admin), Admin::admins_size, f);
    fclose(f);
    for (int i = 0; i < Admin::admins_size; i++)
    {
        admins[i].login = decode_string(admins[i].login);
        admins[i].password = decode_string(admins[i].password);
        admins[i].permission = decode_string(admins[i].permission);
    }
}

void Admin::write_admins()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Admin::admins_size; i++)
    {
        admins[i].login = code_string(admins[i].login);
        admins[i].password = code_string(admins[i].password);
        admins[i].permission = code_string(admins[i].permission);
    }
    FILE* f;
    f = fopen("admins", "w+b");
    fwrite(&Admin::admins_size, sizeof(int), 1, f);
    fwrite(admins, sizeof(Admin), Admin::admins_size, f);
    fclose(f);
    for (int i = 0; i < Admin::admins_size; i++)
    {
        admins[i].login = decode_string(admins[i].login);
        admins[i].password = decode_string(admins[i].password);
        admins[i].permission = decode_string(admins[i].permission);
    }
}
```

Это функции записи и считывания файла в массив админов.

```
string code_string(string str)
{
    char* s;
    s = new char[str.length() + 1];
    strcpy(s, str.c_str());
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        s[i] += code_key;
    }
    string s2(s);
    delete[] s;
    return s2;
}
string decode_string(string str)
{
    char* s;
    s = new char[str.length() + 1];
    strcpy(s, str.c_str());
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        s[i] -= code_key;
    }
    string s2(s);
    delete[] s;
    return s2;
}
```

Это код и декод.
Суть проблемы в том, что при считывании файла у меня вылетает `Access violation writing location 0x0072006D.`
Декод работает правильно и возвращает правильное значение, с таким же размером, как и ориг строка. Массив админов изначально размера 100 и Admin::admins_size это кол-во записанных админов.
При считывании даже первого админа именно на приравнивании `admins[i].login = decode_string(admins[i].login);` вылетает. Там индекс i=0, массив размера 100. В 0 элементе уже есть значение строки в зашифрованном виде

```
User users[100];
Admin admins[100];
string currentLogin;
int code_key = 5;
```

Если убрать строки с кодом-декодом всё работает нормально, записывается и читает

Comment: Использование векторов невозможно, пишу специально код такого уровня. До этого всегда что-то такое работало без проблем (хотя это было относительно давно)

Comment: как это невозможно? вангую что тут массив admins не выделен.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков это описано выше User users[100];
Admin admins[100];
string currentLogin;
int code_key = 5;

Comment: тогда Admin::admins_size равен 1000

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков Я же говорю, что пишу код специально так. Он намерено должен не сильно блистать

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков   Admin::admins_size 1 int
Тем более, что даже если бы был равен 1000, то в момент присваивания i=0 и присваивание идет в нулевой элемент, который уже был забит изначально, там точно есть память

Comment: а ещё есть UB с взятием не инициализированной переменной, многопоточное считывание и прочее прочее без полного кода этого не понять

Comment: компилятор вполне может развернуть цикл если захочет, ни одного запрета на такое я не видел

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101481/discussion-between-dhvcc-and--).